# SoapUI Stuck in Infinite Loop Reading XSDs

Tags: xsd, wsdl, soapui

SoapUI is in an infinite loop trying to read a WSDL file that references a complex set of XSDs. In those XSDs, every file imports all the others it uses, creating cycles. SoapUI continues recursing until we stop it. Here's an example log file:

```
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?WSDL]
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?XSD=xsd/basic_personal_data_creation-0.1.iepdnew/XMLschemas/constraint/XMLschemas/exchange/ExchangeModel.xsd]
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?XSD=xsd/basic_personal_data_creation-0.1.iepdnew/./XMLschemas/constraint/XMLschemas/extension/ExtensionModel.xsd]
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?XSD=xsd/basic_personal_data_creation-0.1.iepdnew/././XMLschemas/constraint/XMLschemas/subset/niem/domains/miem/0.1/miem.xsd]
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?XSD=xsd/basic_personal_data_creation-0.1.iepdnew/./././XMLschemas/constraint/XMLschemas/extension/ExtensionModel.xsd]
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?XSD=xsd/basic_personal_data_creation-0.1.iepdnew/././././XMLschemas/constraint/XMLschemas/subset/niem/domains/miem/0.1/miem.xsd]
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?XSD=xsd/basic_personal_data_creation-0.1.iepdnew/./././././XMLschemas/constraint/XMLschemas/extension/ExtensionModel.xsd]
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?XSD=xsd/basic_personal_data_creation-0.1.iepdnew/././././././XMLschemas/constraint/XMLschemas/subset/niem/domains/miem/0.1/miem.xsd]
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?XSD=xsd/basic_personal_data_creation-0.1.iepdnew/./././././././XMLschemas/constraint/XMLschemas/extension/ExtensionModel.xsd]
Wed Dec 03 17:22:29 EST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [http://dev.soa.REDACTED.us:8001/soa-infra/services/test/TestService/testbpel_client_ep?XSD=xsd/basic_personal_data_creation-0.1.iepdnew/././././././././XMLschemas/constraint/XMLschemas/subset/niem/domains/miem/0.1/miem.xsd]
```

(Scroll to the right to see the ends of the lines.) As you can see, `ExtensionModel.xsd` imports `miem.xsd`, which again imports `ExtensionModel.xsd`, *ad infinitum*. All other tools we've tried recognize the loop and stop recursing. Is there a way to fix this in SoapUI without major surgery on the XSD files?

Comment: What version of SoapUI? I remember reading something like this on their fora. Try upgrading SoapUI.

Comment: @SiKing: I'm told it's "version 5.0.0, the latest".

Comment: Latest is 5.1.2 http://www.soapui.org/Downloads/latest-release.html Try upgrading, see if that solves the problem.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you post a link to the WSDL? You might try their fora, but if you do not have a license, I doubt anyone is going to look at it.

Comment: Or, since it's open sourced at GitHub (https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui), someone could look at the source.